# Deleting db entries not actioning via submit button

Tags: php, mysql

I have a homemade datagrid (table) constructed with DIVS that displays parts relative to a job, i have added a hidden form to add data records, and a button to delete a specific record from two tables however i am unable to get the delete query to execute correctly.

The submit for the delete query has been made as a form button, i also tried using input and a js script to action and then trigger the query but both were unsuccessful, so have tried to keep it simple.

on click of the button the page refreshes as it should at the end of the query (partdel) however the record is not removed, i think that the query isn't receiving the $part_id variable, but i am unsure on how to pass this to it.

due to the design i am needing to do this action within the form and are unsure how to proceed.

any help would be appreciated or even being pointed in the right direction to increase my learning curve.

```
<?php

        ////////////////////////         DELETE FROM PARTS LIST FOR ORDER    //////////////////////////////

        if($_POST['partdel'])
        {
            //Delete part query
            $delQuery = "DELETE FROM job_parts, parts INNER JOIN parts ON parts.part_id = job_parts.part_id WHERE parts.part_id = '$part_id'";  
            $resultDel = mysqli_query($conn, $delQuery);
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Updated!"; 
            header("Location: http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");
            exit;
        }

        ////////////////////////         DISPLAY PARTS DATA RELATIVE TO THE JOB    //////////////////////////////

        if(isset($_GET['id']))  
        {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT part_id, part_name, part_cost, part_rrp, quantity FROM jobs INNER JOIN job_parts USING (job_id) 
            INNER JOIN parts USING (part_id) Where job_id = '$id'");

        echo "<div class='divTable'>
                <div class='divTableBody'>
                <div class='divTableRow'>
                    <div class='divTableHead'>Part Name</div>
                    <div class='divTableHead'>Qty</div>
                    <div class='divTableHead'>Cost Price</div>
                    <div class='divTableHead'>Cost Total</div>
                    <div class='divTableHead'>Retail Price</div>
                    <div class='divTableHead'>Total</div>
                    <div class='divTableHead'></div>
                                        </div>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {   
            $part_id = $row['0'];  //DEFINE VAR FOR part_id.
            $costTotal = $row['2'] * $row['4'];
            $rrpTotal = $row['3'] * $row['4'];

                echo "<div class='divTableRow'>";
                        //echo $part_id;    //used to determin weather the variable has been passed.
                        echo "<div class='divTableCell'>" . $row['1'] . "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='divTableCell'>". $row['4'] . "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='divTableCell'>&pound;" . number_format($costTotal, 2) . "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='divTableCell'>&pound;" . number_format($row['2'], 2) . "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='divTableCell'>&pound;" . number_format($row['3'], 2) . "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='divTableCell'>&pound;" .number_format($rrpTotal, 2) . "</div>";


                        //submit by POST subpartdel where $part_id is captured and record deleted using query $delQuery.                            
                        echo "<form action='' method='POST'><input type='submit' name='partdel' id='partdel' value='Delete'></form>";
                        //end DELETE.


                    echo "</div>";      
            }   
            echo "</div></div>";
        }else
        {
            echo "<H1><b><em>No data to get!</em></b></H1>";
        }

            ////////////////////////         ADD PARTS TO THE JOB VIA HIDDEN INPUT FORM    //////////////////////////////


        ?>
        <script>
        function openForm() {
          document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
        }

        function closeForm() {
          document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
        }
        </script>


        <button class="open-button" onclick="openForm()">Add Part</button>

        <div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
          <form action="" class="form-container" method="POST">
            <h3>Add part</h3>



            <div class="divTable">
                <div class="divTableBody">
                    <div class="divTableRow">
                        <div class="divTableCell"><label for="name"><strong>Name/Description</strong></label></div>
                        <div class="divTableCell"><input id="partName" name="partName" required="" type="text" placeholder="Enter description" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="divTableRow">
                        <div class="divTableCell"><label for="cost"><strong>Cost Price </strong></label></div>
                        <div class="divTableCell"><input id="partCost" name="partCost" required="" type="text" placeholder="Enter cost price" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="divTableRow">
                        <div class="divTableCell"><label for="retail"><strong>Retail Price </strong></label></div>
                        <div class="divTableCell"><input id="partRetail" name="partRetail" required="" type="text" placeholder="Enter retail price" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="divTableRow">
                        <div class="divTableCell"><label for="quantity"><strong>Quantity </strong></label></div>
                        <div class="divTableCell"><input id="partQuantity" name="partQuantity" required="" type="text" placeholder="Enter quantity" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="divTableRow">
                        <div class="divTableCell"><button type="submitpart" name="submitpart" class="btn" onClick="alert('Added!')">Add</button></div>
                        <div class="divTableCell"> <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


          </form>
        </div>
```

my database structure is as follows:

[image: DB Structure]

Comment: Start with checking if your query was realky successful. For now you are just believe it was, which is wrong.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, i have tested the query against my DB and query does successfully remove the correct records.

Comment: Does not prove anything. You tested one query. Your code is still bad. Also your part if is int. What you quote it for in your query?

Comment: You will need to indicate the part_id to be deleted before submitting the form. Add a hidden input, and add JavaScript to the button to set the fields value to the key for the row where the button is located.

Comment: A better practice would be to use AJAX and Javascript to delete the row. This avoids refreshing/reloading the entire page. Take a look at using data attributes (ie. ```data-key='123'```) in a ```<input type='button' ... >``` element. Using a library such as jQuery will make your life a lot easier for forms like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not solve *all* of the problems with your code, however this is too long to be posted as a comment...

This is not valid MySQL syntax :

> DELETE FROM job_parts, parts INNER JOIN parts ON parts.part_id = job_parts.part_id WHERE parts.part_id = '$part_id'"

If you are looking to delete from both tables at once, then this is how to proceed :

```
DELETE jp, p
FROM parts p
INNER JOIN job_parts jp ON jp.part_id = p.part_id    
WHERE p.part_id = ?
```

See this **[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p5RtZQBDotW8J34S53YRYx/0)** (you can uncomment the initial query to see the error it produces).

---

Better yet, if you are looking to mechanize that behavior (ie automatically delete children rows in `job_parts` whenever a parent record is removed from `parts`), then you should just set up a foreign key in table `job_parts` that references `parts`, like :

```
ALTER TABLE job_parts 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (part_id) REFERENCES parts(part_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
;
```

Then you can simply do :

```
DELETE FROM parts WHERE part_id  =?
```

... and rest assured that the children records in `job_parts` were deleted too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, the easiest solution seemed to be the FK alteration, i already had a FK set up however is was set to restrict.

the final query used was as follows:

```
if(isset($_GET['del'])) {
            $del = $_GET['del'];
            mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM parts WHERE part_id=$del");
            //$_SESSION['msg'] = "Part deleted";
            header ('location: http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]');
        }
```